# Is my typescript controller overloaded?

Tags: architecture, typescript, controller

I'm building a rest API using typescript and typeorm as orm. Each route of my API point's to a specific method located in a controller class.

My question is about the content of this controller method. Currently, all my business logic is located right there. For example, the login method for my authentification looks like this.

```
public async login(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({
        select: ["id", "password", "email"],
        where: { email: request.body.email }
    });

    if (!user) {
        response.status(404);
        response.end();
        return;
    }

    const hash = user.password.replace(/^\$2y(.+)$/i, "$2a$1");
    const isVaild = await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, hash);

    if (!isVaild) {
        response.status(403);
        response.end();
        return;
    }

    const payload = {
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600,
        user: { id: user.id, email: user.email }
    };

    const token = await jwt.sign(payload, process.env.APP_KEY);

    response.json({
        accessToken: token,
        expiresAt: payload.exp,
    });
}
```

In my eyes, the method is a little bit overcrowded. Is it useful to break down into smaller pieces of code? If yes, how small should the pice be?

Should I create a service for my authentification logic and only handle the http operations in the controller? What is the best approach?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: As far as I see, your code seems pretty entangled, you are mixing a lot of different logic in your controller method. I can see code responsible for handling http requests/responses, code to do with data access (database query) and code responsible for password hashing all mixed in the same place. Which first of all means that this code has more than one reason to change (Single Responsibility Principle).

I would first, start encapsulating and moving the different responsibilities out of your controller into some independent services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Is this a personal project that only you have to deal with? Is this part of a large enterprise project that other developers might come behind you and have to maintain? Is agility and getting something in front of the customer the most important factor?

The benefit of this code is that it is quick to write. You can release it to your customer and get feedback quickly. You can try to create "perfect" code with layers etc only to find out that it doesn't meet your customer's needs. It's better to find this out sooner than later.

You have to ask yourself constantly, what is the problem with the code? Yes the preferred practice is Single Responsibility, but WHY is that a best practice. It's always up to you and your team to decide what are the pain points and then try to fix them. If this code isn't causing you any pain, I wouldn't waste too much time trying to fix it. Spend time delivering value to your customer/stakeholder.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don’t delivering this code to any customers. Currently I’m working alone at this project. Some big points I’m thinking about are “What if an another developer joins the team?” or “What if when the application goes bigger?”. 

It’s a very good point to ask myself what I really need and what’s the reason behind best practices.

Comment: No problem. There is a term in programming: YAGNI. It stands for You ain't gonna need it. As programmers we like to think of all the what ifs, but a lot of the times you aren't going to need it, so why waste the time on it. Sometimes it can bite you, but experience will teach what things you need to worry about when. Best advice I can give you is KISS, keep it simple stupid, or keep it stupid simple, lol.